# Let `super` call the parent class over an included module

Tags: ruby, inheritance, superclass

I have class `Boy` that inherits class `Person`, and includes module `Bipedal`. Both `Person` and `Bipedal` have versions of `#two_legs`.

```
module Bipedal
  def two_legs(name)
    puts "#{name} has exactly two limbs used for walking."
  end
end

class Person
  def two_legs(name)
    puts "#{name} has two human legs."
  end
end

class Boy < Person
  include Bipedal
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def two_legs
    super(@name)
  end
end
```

Since the `Bipedal` module is included in `Boy`, `Bipedal#two_legs` takes precedence over the `Person#two_legs`. When I call `super` on a `Boy` instance, the module `Bipedal` takes precedence over the parent class `Person`.

```
johnny = Boy.new('Johnny')
johnny.two_legs
# >> "Johnny has exactly two limbs used for walking."
```

I want to use one version in one place and the other in another. `Bipedal` has other stuff, so I can't comment out `include Bipedal`. Is there some standard way to let `Boy#two_legs` or `super` to use the parent class version instead of the module version as follows?

```
johnny.two_legs
# >> "Johnny has two human legs."
```

I came up with this:

```
Boy.superclass.instance_method(:two_legs).bind(self).call(@name)
```

which works in place of `super(@name)`, but is more complicated than I was expecting.

Again, the question is, is there a standard way to force the parent class to take precedence over the module when calling `super`?

Comment: Your use case is not clear. If you want to switch between different methods, why can't they be named as different methods? Why do they have to be named the same? Can you pass some argument to the method, depending on which the method behaves differently?

Comment: Suppose I am not in charge of the module or the superclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use the method [Method#super_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method) twice. That being a garden-variety Ruby method, I believe it would qualify as a "standard way" to let `Boy#two_legs` invoke `Person#two_legs` rather than `Bipedal#two_legs`.

```
class Boy < Person
  include Bipedal
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def two_legs
    method(:two_legs).super_method.super_method.call(@name)
  end
end

willie = Boy.new('Willie')
willie.two_legs
Willie has two human legs.
```

Note the following.

```
willie.method(:two_legs).super_method.owner
  #=> Bipedal
willie.method(:two_legs).super_method.super_method.owner
  #=> Person
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no standard way to force a call to `super` to walk the ancestors in a specific order. They are walked in a pre-defined order. Take a look at [the documentation on calling methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup):

> When you send a message, Ruby looks up the method that matches the name of the message for the receiver. Methods are stored in classes and modules so method lookup walks these, not the objects themselves.
>
> Here is the order of method lookup for the receiver's class or module `R`:
>
> - The prepended modules of `R` in reverse order
> - For a matching method in `R`
> - The included modules of `R` in reverse order
>
> If `R` is a class with a superclass, this is repeated with `R`'s superclass until a method is found.
>
> Once a match is found method lookup stops.

Since your class `Boy` includes the module `Bipedal` directly, and since included modules are searched before the superclass, and since searching stops once a match is found, the superclass `Person` is never checked.

The same is true when using [refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) because the lookup always hits included modules before it checks the superclass.

If you move `include Bipedal` into the `Person` class then it will work the way you expect because `Boy` does not include a module directly, so it will eventually search the superclass where it will find the defined method.

There may be other creative ways you can accomplish this goal, like the `Boy.superclass...` example you gave, but you asked if it's possible to change the lookup behavior when calling `super` and the answer is no per the documentation.

Comment: Shame (or not depending how much sanity you like) that you can't edit `SomeModule.ancestors`.

Comment: I did a quick test, and defining a class method `self.ancestors` in the child class with the desired order does not work. `super` must use some other means of looking up the ancestors. You may be able to find some more info in the [spec for `super`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4444025d16ae1a586eee6a0ac9bdd09e33833f3c/spec/ruby/language/super_spec.rb).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change how `super` works and you can't "`super super`" to skip an ancestor but you can use a different ancestor. If you're just including `Bipedal` for some of its methods and want to skip a few of them then you could do something like this:

```
SemiBipedal = Bipedal.dup
SemiBipedal.remove_method(:two_legs)

class Boy < Person
  include SemiBipedal
  #...
end
```

Of course `johnny.is_a? Bipedal` won't be true anymore and `Boy.ancestors` will have `SemiBipedal` instead of `Bipedal` at index 1 but that might not matter.

Comment: I love this idea, but when I typed it in, I couldn’t get it to work. I get “private method ‘remove_method’ called for SemiBipedal:Module (NoMethodError)”.

Comment: The only place that remove_method seems to work is within the Bipedal module itself…

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? `remove_method` doesn't appear to be private in 2.5.3. You can always `SemiBipedal.send(:remove_method, :two_legs)` or `module SemiBipedal; remove_method :two_legs; end` to kludge around that.

Comment: I was using 2.4.0 but I updated it to 2.5.3, re-ran the code (copied straight from yours) and it still gives me that private method error. `SemiBipedal.send(:remove_method, :two_legs)` works great. Maybe the most straightforward way is to skip an alias module and add `Bipedal.send(:remove_method, :two_legs)` directly to `Boy`, assuming `Boy` doesn't need the `Bipedal` version...

Comment: But `Bipedal.send(:remove_method, :two_legs)` modifies `Bipedal` so everything that uses the module will be affected, hence the copy of `Bipedal` (not alias) and removing `two_legs` from the copy.